# Html table, rowspan issue

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to build a table like this:

[image: https://1.downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/9c8cf709ffa53f75f44349c9fb512249/mpfs/9_71meRPOf9sZVtYIMSzTXIIQmirBLFxpBYkuucgBrZF3zDeVP6jDh2dOMBOYp-YwgO-1B-vBTiWWeE3VvxiDA%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=tablepng&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&size=XXL&crop=0]

Here is my solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="6"></td>
                <td rowspan="3"></td>
                <td rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td rowspan="3"></td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
            <tr><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems to be logical, but it doesn't work at any browser. Is there any way in HTML to build such table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only had 3 rows, so that was never going to work. As you defined your first cell with `rowspan="6"` then you need at least 6 rows.

You can layout the cells by imagining 6 rows across the diagram and then you can see which row a given cell starts. The following diagram shows the each cell in order of first encounter;

[image]

So the following code will produce that layout;

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="6">&nbsp;</td> <!-- Box 1 -->
                <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td> <!-- Box 2 -->
                <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td> <!-- Box 3 -->
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr><td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr> <!-- Box 4 -->
            <tr><td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr> <!-- Box 5 -->
            <tr><td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr> <!-- Box 6 -->
            <tr></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `&nbsp;`s were so I could see the structure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #999">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lkq2wq3s/)**

Comment: Not the downvoter, but probably meta affect: [Is this a case of reputation bias?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269925/is-this-a-case-of-reputation-bias)

Comment: As far as you know! Do you want me to prove by upvoting?

Comment: @worldofjr lol no, I meant we both got dinged for no apparent reason, but Khior didn't (you can see up and down votes once you have enough rep). I was just kidding, I have no idea who downvoted. Fact of life here on SO.

Comment: @j08691 I see, just the way the cookie crumbles!

Comment: It could be because your answer does not explain anything. It's a code only-answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can stick with 6/3/2 rowspan, but you need to include the empty rows you are spanning. For example:

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="6">6</th>
        <td rowspan="3">3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!-- empty row --></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="3">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">2</td></tr>
    <tr><!-- empty row --></tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle riddle diddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bounj7oL/)